# I cannot compile the Data_vs170.sln in Visual Studio 2022 - error on SQLParser

Tags: compilation, visual-studio-2022

I usually compile the POCO library in the following order, and only include the projects I will use:
CppUnit
Foundation
XML
JSON
Util
Net
Data
Data/ODBC
Zip

It has worked well until the latest POCO version, in which the SQLParser was added. Now the Data_vs170.sln will not compile because it cannot find the sql-parser/src/SQLParser.h file.
I want a way to compile the Data_vs170.sln WITHOUT the SQLParser.

Would please someone instruct me how to do so?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Eduardo Quintana

Answer (score 0):

Assuming poco was extracted in pocosrc dir, I was able to compile by adding include path to my project settings: ....\pocosrc\Data\src

Comment: The problem is that the compiler is looking for the dir sql-parser and it is not in the distribution zip file. An error example is:
E:\poco\Data\include\Poco\Data\SQLParser.h(26,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sql-parser/src/SQLParser.h': No such file or directory
(compiling source file 'src/RecordSet.cpp')

Answer (score 0):

In the file of Config.h, at the last line, cancel the annotation at "// #define POCO_DATA_NO_SQL_PARSER".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have done as suggested and the same errors are shown as I try to rebuild the Data project:

"/src/sql-parser/src/SQLParserResult.cpp(1,1): error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\sql-parser\src\SQLParserResult.cpp': No such file or directory"

"/src/sql-parser/src/parser/flex_lexer.cpp(1,1): error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'src\sql-parser\src\parser\flex_lexer.cpp': No such file or directory"

Among several other errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The files reported as not found and that are shown in the project explorer in the VS 2022 IDE are not present in the Poco dir or sub-dirs.

They simply are not part of the distribution.

What should I do?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana I encountered the same issue as you did while compiling POCO in VS2022. However, upon uncommenting that line, the error vanished since defining “POCO_DATA_NO_SQL_PARSER” prevents the MS compiler from searching for the SQLParser source code.

Comment: The new POCO version 1.13.2 corrected this problem and now it compiles without any problem.